# convert arabic numeric html entities to chars via PHP

Tags: php, character-encoding, html-entities

I have some string with arabic encoded and ukrainian (cyrillyc) words, like this:

```
$string = "&#1575;&#1616;&#1574;&#1618;&#1578;&#1616;&#1604;&#1575;&#1601;&#1616;&#1610;&#1617;&#1612; - коаліційний, гармонійний;";
```

and I want to get characters (arabic) instead all this "&#xxxx;"`s.

If I putting this string into html, I'm getting exactly what i want:
"اِئْتِلافِيٌّ - коаліційний, гармонійний;"

But when I use html_entitis_decode, it does nothing. (mb because arabic encoding does not supports with this function, just basic ASCII).
So, plz tell me what should I do to get same result as browser interpreter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your PHP version is probably older than **5.4.0**, thus `html_entity_decode` is not using **UTF-8**.

> Encoding to use. If omitted, the default value for this argument is ISO-8859-1 in versions of PHP prior to 5.4.0, and UTF-8 from PHP 5.4.0 onwards.

<sup>http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php</sup>

---

Try the following:

```
$decoded_string = html_entity_decode($string, ENT_COMPAT | ENT_HTML401, "UTF-8");
```

[View output here on Codepad](http://codepad.org/NqFRJt0a)

Comment: I use php 5.3.13, thrue. and the part of problem was that text, I used to encode was in ANSI encoding, so, after conversion I always got half of text encoded wrongly. Thanks for help